# how to work out the search complexity of a function

Tags: c++, big-o

I have the following two functions and i am trying to compare the time complexity
my first function is a simple for loop:

```
For (i=0;i<m;i++)
// do stuff
```

Time complexity:

> i=0 is executed once
>
> i< n is executed n+1 times
>
> i++ is executed n times
>
> = 2n+2 = 0(N)

i am struggling to work out my time complexity for this second function:

```
void search(string word)
{
    Index index;
    if (tree.AVL_Retrieve(word, index)) {
        for (auto i : index.idList)
        {
            
             for (int j=0;j<m;j++)              
                 {
                    //do stuff
                  }
        }   
    }
}
```

i believe that retrieve in AVL tree is O(logN) and my loop is O(N) and then my inner loop is O(M), but as a whole how would i write the time complexity for that search function.

note: we can assume there are N keys in my AVL tree

Comment: In my second function, the loop contains a search function that is O(N), does that not affect the overall time complexity ?

Comment: which search function?

Comment: please see updated question

Comment: With the nested loops it would be `O(N²)`

Comment: Only if n and m are same.. Consider an example where you have a 3*1 matrix... i.e., n = 3 and m = 1... in that case would n*m be same as n^2(I really do not know how you are typing that superscript)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first for loop runs for `(m-1)` times, thus having time complexity O(m).

The second function runs the `AVL_Retrieve` function once and for each loop count of index.idList times, giving the complexity `O(log (number of nodes in tree))+O((count of index.idList)*m)`

Comment: Would that simplify into O(n*m)?

Comment: @william_, Provided number of nodes in the tree is same as count of index.idList

Comment: It I would be, so essentially a linear search would be more efficient than combing a avl tree retrieve with a loop